# RegularExpressionValidator and ValidationSummary text displayed but not summary

Tags: asp.net, validation

Can I use clientscript in validation controls while also having my own onblur event?  The trouble Im having is getting the validationsummary to be displayed, but the text shows beside each textbox, just not the summary.

Validation controls:

```
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTimeFrameFrom" style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;" onblur="javascript:updatePackageTime1(this);" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameFrom")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="grpValidTimeFrame" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic" Text="<font color='red'>*</font>" ErrorMessage='check format in time from' ControlToValidate="txtTimeFrameFrom" ID="ValidTimeFrameFrom" ValidationExpression="^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$" runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTimeFrameTo" style="width:50px;font-size:x-small;" onblur="javascript:updatePackageTime2(this);" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TimeFrameTo")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="grpValidTimeFrame" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic" Text="<font color='red'>*</font>" ErrorMessage='check format in time to' ControlToValidate="txtTimeFrameTo" ID="ValidTimeFrameTo" ValidationExpression="^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\040(AM|am|PM|pm)$" runat="server"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

ValidationSummary:

```
                         <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="grpValidTimeFrame" id="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"  HeaderText="You received the following errors:"> </asp:ValidationSummary>
```

When I enter a value in one of the textboxes that cause a validation error, I see a message in the bottom of the browser window (chrome) that seems to indicate a javascript problem (javascript:void(0))

Answer (score 0):

If you set the display to `None` then it shows the `ErrorMessage` only in the ValdiationSummary.

```
Display="None"
```

And why this? `Text="<font color='red'>*</font>"`. Better keep thing neat and clean and give your validators their own class

```
CssClass="myValidator"

<style>
.myValidator { color: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: ok, but the summary isnt showing up at all, even with display=none on the validation controls

Comment: It does when I copied your snippet. You may want to test it on a blank page without any other JavaScript.